# How can I run a func that lives in a seperate View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, global, func

I have an app wherein once navigated to a second page and shown some results, the user has the option of running the same function but with some different parameters.

I am stuck on figuring out how to run the func that is inside my initial screen from within my second...

I have tried several methods but seem to get stuck. I have tried moving the func to my `@main` struct as well and having it be global. seems there are some linking issues as I'm doing it wrong. I have placed `ContentView.doFunction()` as an example of where I need to run the func from, this obviously doesn't work and is a bit more pythonic..

I will provide a very basic reproduction of the code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var readyToNavigate: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: doFunction, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
                    secondPage()}
                .navigationTitle("Test")
            }
        }
    }
    func doFunction() {
        Task {
            let example = await "This is running an async operation"
            print(example)
        }
        readyToNavigate = true
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

and from the other view which is in a seperate swift file...

```
struct secondPage: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("run func from first page", action: {
//            ContentView.doFunction()
            print("running async func from ContentView")
        })
    }
}
#Preview {
    secondPage()
}
```

Comment: ContentView.doFunction() will never work for a number of reasons. You should start with the Apple SwiftUI tutorials. SwiftUI views are not like other struct.

Comment: As I said in the question, I know this doesn’t work, it was just a placeholder for logic.

Comment: And my answer applies to anything that would make something similar compile. You shouldn’t access properties and functions of a View from the top/outside. You can only access properties from a child that has a two-way connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI use async/await with `.task` not `Task {}`, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var readyToNavigate: Bool = false
    @State private var isRunning = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button(isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start") {
                    isRunning.toggle()
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
                    SecondPage()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Test")
            }
        }
        .task(id: isRunning) { // runs on appear and cancelled and restarted when id changes, cancelled on dissapear
             if isRunning == false { return }
             await doFunction()
             isRunning = false
        }
    }

    func doFunction() async {
        let example = await "This is running an async operation"
        print(example)
        readyToNavigate = true
    }
}
```

If you want to restart the function from a child `View` then you can pass a `Binding` in to allow write access to the same State that is used as the `id` in `.task`.

Comment: Thank you @malhal, using .task and updating id: seems to work much better. I am still having an issue. The isRunning variable is false on start and then changes to true on Button press and runs, then changes back to false, this works perfectly. When i am on SecondPage() though and I update the isRunning variable to true again though, it doesn't run the .task from the first page. Do I need to recreate another instance of the first page again for it to work? If so, how would I do that? Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: .task only runs when visible. Just move the .task higher up the view hierarchy to be attached to a View that is always on screen eg the `NavigationStackView`. Then pass the id binding down to both places you want to start it from.

Comment: That was a really great question by the way

Answer (score 1):

`ContentView.doFunction` is calling a static function in ContentView, not a single instance itself. And of course, it will not work.

If you want a couple views to share the same functionality, you might think about a kind of `ViewModel`, passing around.

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var readyToNavigate = false

    func doFunction() {
        //I don't know why you put await without any async task here. Just remove it.
        let example = "This is running an async operation"
        print(example)
        readyToNavigate = true
    }
}
```

Then in your views:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    viewModel.doFunction()
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.readyToNavigate) {
                    SecondPage(viewModel: viewModel)}
                .navigationTitle("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondPage: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Button("run func from first page", action: {
            viewModel.doFunction()
            print("running async func from ContentView")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems very inefficient to allocate a heap object just to call a function

Comment: @malhal Perhaps at a _huge_ scale, but as presented, the allocation is done once, with one object. This doesn't seem inefficient.

Comment: yep as long as you don't make an object every time you only need a function

Comment: I think it is quite acceptable, I am assuming the OP needs to do some task, with the same behavior and maybe different input parameters. Btw, thanks for your comment, I will notice next time.

Comment: Yes, I will be on a “results” style page with text displayed. Hitting the button on this page will call the  doFunction() func which contains an async post request and several other non-async funcs. Results will be displayed to the user on the same page they are on (I assume the page text will update without a View change). I am yet to run these solutions so not 100% sure if it works for me yet.

Comment: If so, you should have some `@Published` properties on the viewModel. Then binding it to every single view you're passing by. Then everytime you do some async tasks on viewModel, it will relay to the views which are listening. In the given example above, I just see a `readyToNavigate`, which presents `navigationDestination`, so I can't give you any advice.